# Function to read an array list from file and display on the screen

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

I'm trying to write a method to read an array list from a file and then display it on the screen but it doesn't work at the end. Here is the method I'm using:

Description:

- Point class contains constructor, getter, setter, toString()
- PrintPoint class contains constructor, print method, and read from file method
- TestPoint class to test

Point class

```
public class Point {
    
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private String name;
    
    public Point(String name, double x, double y){
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    //setter and getter
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + "[" + this.x + ", " + this.y + "]";
    }
}
```

PrintPoint class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class PrintPoint {
    
    private ArrayList<Point> pointList;
    
    //Constructor
    public PrintPoint(String path) throws FileNotFoundException{
      pointList = getPointFromFile(path);
    }
    
    //Print method
    public void printPointList(){
      for(Point p : pointList){
        System.out.println(p);
      }
    }

    //Read from file method
    public ArrayList<Point> getPointFromFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException{
        try {
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(new File(path));
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                list.add(myReader.nextLine());
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ArrayList<Point>();
    }
}
```

TestPoint class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TestPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        PrintPoint a = new PrintPoint("arraylist.txt");
        a.printPointList();
    }
}
```

arraylist.txt

```
A,3,4
B,5,6
C,7,8
```

I want to print the array list but it doesn't work (no error just not print).

UPDATED: I have updated the question with another requirement.

Comment: You’re returning an empty ArrayList from your getPointFromFile() method

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to autocomplete your functions? Because if you forgot a `return`, Eclipse would suggest exactly that. I recommend *not* leaning heavily on your IDE starting out, as it often has poor suggestions based on a limited understanding of your code, especially in languages like Java where the type system conveys very little information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert lines of text in file `arraylist.txt` to `Point` objects.

Below is the code for class `PrintPoint` since this was the only class that I changed.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintPoint {
    private ArrayList<Point> pointList;

    // Constructor
    public PrintPoint(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        pointList = getPointFromFile(path);
    }

    // Print method
    public void printPointList() {
        for (Point p : pointList) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    // Read from file method
    public ArrayList<Point> getPointFromFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
        try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(new File(path))) {
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = myReader.nextLine();
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                String name = fields[0];
                double x = Double.parseDouble(fields[1]);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);
                Point pt = new Point(name, x, y);
                list.add(pt);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

- Note that the above code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- If you declare that method `getPointFromFile` throws `FileNotFoundException`, then you shouldn't handle it in the method. Either remove the `throws FileNotFoundException` in the method declaration or remove the `try-catch`. In the code above, I removed the `try-catch`.

Below is the output I got when I ran the above code.

```
A[3.0, 4.0]
B[5.0, 6.0]
C[7.0, 8.0]
```

Alternatively, if you are using at least Java 8, you can use the [streams API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html).

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class PrintPoint {
    private List<Point> pointList;

    // Constructor
    public PrintPoint(String path) throws IOException {
        pointList = getPointFromFile(path);
    }

    // Print method
    public void printPointList() {
        for (Point p : pointList) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }

    public List<Point> getPointFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get(path);
        return Files.lines(p)
                    .map(line -> {
                        String[] fields = line.split(",");
                        return new Point(fields[0],
                                         Double.parseDouble(fields[1]),
                                         Double.parseDouble(fields[2]));
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re returning an empty ArrayList from your getPointFromFile() method, so it doesn't print anything on console output.

You have read data from file, but not construct the `Point` object. I don't know what the data `arraylist.txt` is, there is a sample for you:

```
    //Read from file method
    public ArrayList<Point> getPointFromFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(new File(path));
            // ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                // list.add(myReader.nextLine());
                String ps = myReader.nextLine();
                String[] split = ps.split(",");
                Point point = new Point(Double.parseDouble(split[0]),Double.parseDouble(split[1]));
                result.add(point);
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

arraylist.txt：

```
10,20
34,56
199,23
```

console output:

```
[10.0, 20.0]
[34.0, 56.0]
[199.0, 23.0]
```