# ArrayList as parameter for Constructor and problem about read an array list from file

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

I've tried to work to solve these problems for 3 days and it doesn't work as I expected. Here is the description and the code:

Description:

- Person class
- Student class inherit from Person: the most important is the data type of attribute favSubject is ArrayList
- Teacher class inherit from Person
- PrintInfo class contains: Constructor, print method, and read from file methods

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    
    protected String name;
    
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    //setter and getter
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student extends Person {
    
    private String id;
    private ArrayList<String> favSubject;
    private double score;
    
    public Student(String name, String id, ArrayList<String> favSubject, double score){
        super(name);
        this.id = id;
        this.favSubject = favSubject;
        this.score = score;
    }
    
    //setter and getter
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + "-" + this.id + "-" + this.favSubject + "-" + this.score;
    }
}
```

Teacher class:

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
    
    private String subject;
    
    public Teacher(String name, String subject){
        super(name);
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    
    //setter and getter
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + "-" + this.subject;
    }
}
```

PrintInfo class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;
public class PrintInfo {
    
    private ArrayList<Person> persList;
    
    //Constructor
    public PrintInfo(String path, String path1) throws FileNotFoundException{
      persList = getInfoFromFile(path, path1);
    }
    
    //Print method
    public void printInfoList(){
      for(Person p : persList){
        System.out.println(p);
      }
    }

    //Read from file method
    public ArrayList<Person> getInfoFromFile(String path, String path1) throws FileNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            
            //this code is hidden because of privacy

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TestPerson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        PrintInfo a = new PrintInfo("ListOfPerson.txt", "FSInfo.txt");
        a.printInfoList();
    }
}
```

I want to read data from 2 files ListOfPerson(basic information) and FSInfo(favorite subject for favSubject attribute) with the method getInfoFromFile() and then display it on the screen

ListOfPerson.txt:

Structure:

- Student: order, ID, name, score
- Teacher: order, name, subject

```
1, A01, David, 10
2, Kate, Physics
3, A02, John, 9
4, A03, Olivia, 9
5, Helen, Math
6, A04, Sarah, 8
7, Nick, History
8, A05, Jennie, 10
9, A06, Jeremy, 9
10, Mary, Chemistry
```

FSInfo.txt:

Structure: id, favorite subject

```
A01, Math, Physics
A02, Physics
A03, Chemistry, History
A04, Math, Geography
A05, Chemistry
A06, Biology
```

What I want to display on the screen:

```
David - A01 - [Math,Physics] - 10
Kate - Physic
John - A02 - [Physics] - 9
Olivia - A03 - [Chemistry,History] - 9
Helen - Math
Sarah - A04 - [Math,Geography] - 8
Nick - History
Jennie - A05 - [Chemistry] - 10
Jeremy - A06 - [Biology] - 9
Mary - Chemistry
```

This is just the beginning of the exercise so I have to solve this problem for a few more requirements.
Thank you so much :))

UPDATE: Problem Solved :)) Thanks, everyone.

Comment: My suggestion: I would not mix teachers and students in the same list. This just complicates things.

Comment: I would not mix them either, @NomadMaker, or if I did mix them then I would use a format that more clearly distinguished which is which.  But I take the format of the input files to be part of the assignment, not open for modification.

Comment: This question seems very similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249121/function-to-read-an-array-list-from-file-and-display-on-the-screen).

Answer (score 0):

> - Student class inherit from Person: the most important is the data type of attribute favSubject is ArrayList

You've left us to guess why the data type of the `favSubject` is of special importance.  I'm still not sure I see it.  What I do see with respect to this attribute, however, is that the data for it are recorded in a separate file from the main person data.  Since you need the `favSubject` data for a `Student` at construction time, you have two main alternatives:

1. Each time you recognize that you need to construct a `Student`, read the favorite subject file to find that student's favorite subjects.
2. Read and parse the whole favorite subject file *first*, storing the results in a form that is easy to access later.  Personally, I would use a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`, with student ID as key and favorite subject list as value.

Of those, I recommend the latter, as it is both more efficient and more modular (making it easier to write, to understand, and to debug).

The other main issue for you may be how to distinguish between students and teachers in the person list file. The easiest difference to recognize between these is probably the number of fields, so consider reading the file a full line at a time

```
String line = myReader.nextLine();
```

, splitting the lines into fields on the `,`  delimiters

```
String[] fields = line.split(", *");
```

, and using the field count to differentiate between students (4 fields) and teachers (3 fields). That also gives you a head start on the constructor parameters.

That's as much as I am prepared to give you by way of hints.  As a matter of code style, however, I observe that `path` and `path1` are singularly uninformative names for your method parameters, especially in the absence of any code documentation.  I suggest more descriptive names that, especially, identify which path is for which file.

Comment: I've redited the code and it works but it doesn't print the favSubject array list (it's just print David - A01 - [] - 10). Can you check for me?

Comment: @huy_tran_2308, I don't follow why you are performing such gymnastics with the favorite subjects.  When you need the favorite subject list for a student, why not just retrieve it from the Map and use it as is?

Comment: @huy_tran_2308, the code now presented in the question appears to do the job correctly, provided that no student has more than two. If it doesn't seem to be doing the job then I would suggest using a debugger to trace its behavior.  It is your convoluted approach to getting the data back out that seems questionable to me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've fixed it and it runs successfully <3